# Help regarding understanding derivation of electrostatic potential in a solution to a problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, gauss-law

I was looking at the solution of finding the energy stored in a charged solid sphere in which the electric field was

[image]

and then later stated the electrostatic potential is

[image]

I  understand that to get $V$ from $E$ when $r>R$ is simply integration, but for when $r<R$ where does the negative and the additional term come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably for charged solid **sphere**, not a cylinder. In any case, setting the potential at infinity as zero, we have for $r>R$:
$$V(r)-V(\infty)=-\int_\infty^rE(r')dr'\implies V(r)=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}$$
For $r<R$, we got:
$$V(r)-V(\infty)=-\int_\infty^rE(r')dr'=-\int_\infty^RE(r')dr'-\int_R^rE(r')dr' \implies \\
V(r)=-\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\left.-\frac{1}{r'}\right|_{r'=\infty}^R \left.+\frac{r'^2}{2R}\right|_{r'=R}^r\right) \implies\\
V(r)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{r^2}{2R^3}+\frac{1}{2R}\right)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(-\frac{r^2}{2R^3}+\frac{3}{2R}\right)$$

Comment: How did you get $\frac{1}{R}$?

Comment: Integrating $\int_\infty^REdr$. It will just yield the same result as the first part when $r=R$.

Comment: Could you explain why that is?

Comment: Added one more line, see if it's clearer now.